# How can I catch a spring message JstTagException?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, localization, sitemesh

I'm using Spring MVC 3.0 with sitemesh and spring message bundles.  For example, I have the following:

```
<spring:message code="nav.item.name"/>
```

If nav.item.name does not exist in my resource file, I receive a blank page and a JspTagException in the console, which I can't catch with my @ExceptionHandler method.  I'm assuming I can't catch it because the error is part of the view rendering.  I've also tried to create a custom HandlerInterceptorAdapter, and modify the web.xml both with no success. Interestingly enough, I've also used the following tag:

```
<fmt:message key="nav.item.name"/>
```

And the view shows the page, but with "???????" for the text.  This is actually more acceptable to me to at least show the page, but I would rather use the spring:message tags.

My question is: How do I catch the JspTagException?

Stack Trace:

2011-10-12 09:31:16,155 ERROR [http-8080-2] RequestContextAwareTag - No message found under code 'BLAH' for locale 'ko_KR'.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'BLAH' for locale 'ko_KR'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.common.nav_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(nav_jsp.java:206)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.common.nav_jsp._jspService(nav_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.sitemesh_002ddecorators.main_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(main_jsp.java:284)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.sitemesh_002ddecorators.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.OldDecorator2NewDecorator.render(OldDecorator2NewDecorator.java:46)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:33)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use Spring's exception handling mechanism because that is higher in the call. The JSP exception occurs later.

If you set [the `text` attribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.message) to some value, does it show that value instead of throwing the exception?

To clear the exception, you might provide the tag with a default message (the [MessageSource.getMessage(...)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html#getMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) method has an overload taking such a `defaultMessage`).

If you have no default to show but still want to warn the user about missing keys (instead of having an exception thrown or a white page), why not display the actual missing `code`?

You can do that by using the `UseCodeAsDefaultMessage` property on the `MessageSource` bean. See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractMessageSource.html#setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage%28boolean%29) and [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractMessageSource.html#isUseCodeAsDefaultMessage%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, I am using dynamic properties, so I need to catch it when no key-value exists or alert the user instead of showing a blank page.  If a user sets up my application incorrectly, for example, accidentally deleting a key-value pair that is being used it will just show a blank page.  I'll add the stack trace to the original post.

Comment: @Dave: I've updated my answer based on your comment. See if it helps. I've kept part of the initial answer for completeness.

Comment: Thank you!!  The UseCodeAsDefaultMessage will work well for me!